# CSS increase container width when text inside overflows to the right?

Tags: html, css, layout, horizontal-scrolling, column-width

When you do something like:

```css
.container {
  column-width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  ... a lot of text...
</div>
```

If the text is large enough it will cause that the corresponding text overflows the container width to the right. That's awesome if you want an horizontal layout, however, the div width won't grow because the text has "overflow" the container. If you put a background to the div you will see that the background won't be there after the end of the screen (if the text is sufficienty large). That why, if you put a second div next to this one in an horizontal fashion, the second  will be over the overflowed content of the first div, which is undesirable.

The question is: how can I make the first div be adjusted to the content inside him no matter how large it becomes in the horizontal line?

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do it like this (if i understood what you want)

```
.container {
  width: auto;
  height: 300px;
}

.text{
Padding-left: 10%;
Padding-right: 10%;
}
<div class="container">
 <div class="text">
 ... a lot of text...
</div>
</div
```

The container should now change size depending on the text. :)

Comment: you are not considering the case of `column-width: 200px` property. In this case, the width of the container won't grow beyond the screen width. It seem that when the text  overflows its container size, it gets out the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

With [CSS3 Intrinsic Sizing,](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/) you can use this: `width: max-content` which expands the width of the parent container based on text it encloses.

**Caution** - not supported in IE. Check this: https://caniuse.com/#search=max-content

Comment: Nice one, wasn't aware of this option!